# Reading an ArrayList Faster

Tags: java, performance, arraylist

I am writing a solver for a crossword puzzle that reads in a dictionary file and given  a pattern returns a list of all words that fit that pattern. I have the functionality working but I need this to work faster. I create a HashMap with the length of words being the key and an ArrayList of the words as the value. Is there someway I can read through the ArrayList faster or is there some better data structure to use?

```
import java.util.*;

public class CWSolution {

    //create the data structure that will store the dictionary
    private HashMap<Integer,ArrayList<String>> db;

    public CWSolution(List<String> allWords)
    {

    //construct the background structure

        //Create hashmap
        db = new HashMap<Integer,ArrayList<String>>();

        //go through each word
        for(String item : allWords ){
            //if the db does not contain a listing for this word length, create one
            if(!db.containsKey(item.length())){
                ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>();
                temp.add(item);
                db.put(item.length(), temp);
            }
            //if it does contain a listing for this word length, add this word to it
            else{
                ArrayList<String> temp = db.get(item.length());
                temp.add(item);
                db.put(item.length(), temp);
            }
        }
    }

    public List<String> solutions(String pattern, int maxRequired)
    {

        //actually look for each pattern

        //create the structures we need
        List<String> answer = new ArrayList<String>();

        //get the relevant array list
        ArrayList<String> temp = db.get(pattern.length());

        //go through the array list word by word
        for(String item : temp ){
            //see if the pattern matches the word, if it does add it to the list, otherwise skip it
            if(matchPattern(pattern, item)){
                answer.add(item);
            }
            //if we reach the required size return it, otherwise keep going
            if(answer.size() == maxRequired){
                return answer;
            }
        }
        return answer;
    }

    private boolean matchPattern(String pattern, String word){
        //TODO implement this function
        //check the word against the pattern
        char star = "*".charAt(0);
        for(int i=0;i<pattern.length();i++){
            if(pattern.charAt(i) != star){
                if(pattern.charAt(i) != word.charAt(i)){
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** 
Adding some more information to make this more clear.

Some of the comments were debating this so figured I'd clarify, I am a student in a Data Structures course so there is only so much that I know about, but we are nearing the end of the semester so I have a good idea of basic data structures.

Furthermore I am not as concerned about optimizing the CWSolution() method a I am with optimizing the solutions() method. The speed is being tested as follows and what I am really concerned with is Time2. That is how long it takes to find matching words rather than how long it takes to create the structure.

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;


public class CWSpeedTest {

    public static void main(String[] args){
    try{
        FileParser fp = new FileParser("TWL06.txt");
        List<String> solutions = null;
        //Change this to change the pattern
        String pattern = "*S**"; 
        //Change this to change the max solutions
        int maxSolns = 2000;

        List<String> dict = fp.getAllWords();

        Date d1 = new Date();
        CWSolution c = new CWSolution(dict);
        Date d2 = new Date();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        solutions = c.solutions(pattern,maxSolns);
        Date d3 = new Date();
        System.out.println("Time 1: " + (d2.getTime() - d1.getTime()));
        System.out.println("Time 2: " + (d3.getTime() - d2.getTime()));
        System.out.println("For the pattern: " + pattern);
        System.out.println("With max solutions: " + maxSolns);
        System.out.println(solutions);

    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Off the top of my head: the data structure you probably want, after filtering by length, is something like a `Map<Integer, Map<Character, Set<String>>>` - the `Set` is all the words that have the given `Character` at the position given by the `Integer`. You then go over characters in the pattern, get the `Set`s from this map for all the specified characters, and successively do intersections of these sets.

Comment: I'd probably actually use a thin wrapper after this `Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Map<Character, Set<String>>>>`because that amount of angle brackets is painful. What you're really looking for is a multidimensional matrix. Alternatively, you could create a separate class `DictionaryKey` for the map key with the fields `length`, `position`, and `character`. Have your IDE generate a `hashCode()` using those fields, and then use a `Map<DictionaryKey, Set<String>>` to make the code more readable. This way you could microoptimise a bit by making `DictionaryKey` immutable and memoising the hash code.

Comment: This doesn't help, if your pattern starts with a couple of stars. You need to index upon all possible positions.

Comment: @BorisBrodski That's what I mean. Say the map for `length -> position -> character -> words` is called `db`. You would store the word "puppy" under the length `5`, and the `position, character` keys `0, 'p'`, `1, 'u'`, `2, 'p'` etc. (Each word would be indexed by each character in the word, not just the starting word. That's precisely why the key is `position, character`.) Then if you're looking for words that match `**ppy`, you get the sets `db[2]['p']`, `db[3]['p']`, and `db[4]['y']`. I'd code it up but I'm busy ATM, and if this is homework doing so would be a great exercise for the OP ;)

Comment: As for why my approach is a significant improvement. The OP's code, if I'm reading it correctly, iterates over, say `total_words/10` words. (Assuming that most of the words have a length between `3` and `13`. The exact length distribution doesn't actually matter since my algorithm filters by word length too.) Then it performs `word_length` character comparisons for each of those words. This is possibly a large number if the dictionary is big.

Comment: My proposed algorithm fetches a bunch of sets that are of size `total_words/(10*26)` - all the words of a given length with the given character at a certain position. This is already a set an order of magnitude smaller than the one before. Then you do a bunch of set intersections, which take as many hash lookups as is the size of the smaller set. As an optimisation you can deliberately start with the smallest set you find. The total number of *additional* hash lookups when doing the intersections should be close to `word_length * total_results`, which should be a small number.

Comment: @millimoose Thanks for your response. I do not fully understand what you are proposing could you elaborate on your solution more.

Comment: To summarise, if `N` is the number of words in the dictionary, and `m` is the length of the current word, the OP's approach is `O((N * m) / 10)`. Mine is `O(N / 260)` and some change. Seeing how `m` is likely to be modest it's the same complexity class, but still at least an order of magnitude faster.

Comment: @millimoose This is a cool idea, just posted another answer with almost the same ideas. I also thought about finding second shortest list and do an intersection, but remembered, that databases never use more that one index doing linear searches afterwards. In short, if you have list/set sizes: 10000 10000 10 10000 10000 doing intersection with the second shortest list will waste a lot of time.

Comment: @BorisBrodski Are you sure about that reasoning? Databases use indexing to save I/O operations as well as CPU time. In this case everything is in memory already so this doesn't translate directly. In your example, doing the intersections would require no more than 50 hash lookups. This is exactly as many operations as a worst-case linear search for a word of length `5` would take. (And all of this is glossing over the `*`s in the pattern. The more there are, the less complex the string comparison is, but the less selective the index will be. So it's hard to tell where this will even out.)

Comment: @BorisBrodski Or to rephrase that: you're not wrong, and not right either. (And neither am I.) It would take a comprehensive test case to see where the break-even point is between linear scans and doing more intersections. Where linear scans are better for patterns with more `'*'`s, and set operations are better for more selective patterns.

Comment: @millimoose I think now that your approach is better. I overlooked, that Sets can perform cross section within O(min(size1,size2)). I updated my answer, that now actually more our answer :)

Comment: @BorisBrodski - I have a belated observation that just clicked: Databases don't "never use more than one index". They have a query planner that determines what the right implementation for a given query step is. The query planner does the decision that I mentioned on the fly based on the expected sizes of the intermediate results.

Comment: Of course, the planner decides, when and which index to use. But for a single table selection maximally one index get used. On the other hand a database index can't be compared with the Set class. So calculating cross sections looks like a better way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is complete rewrite of the algorithm using indexing on all positions and characters. First this algorithm finds the shortest list of the words with a specified character at the specified position found in the pattern. Then it calculates cross section with all other lists of the words (one list per non-star character in the pattern).

```
import java.util.*;

public class CWSolution {

    class FixLengthDB {
        // Index -> Letter -> All word with the Letter at Index
        HashMap<Integer, HashMap<Character, Set<String>>> indexLetterDb = new HashMap<>();

        public void storeWord(String word) {
            int l = word.length();
            for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
                HashMap<Character, Set<String>> letterDb = indexLetterDb.get(i);
                if (letterDb == null) {
                    letterDb = new HashMap<>();
                    indexLetterDb.put(i, letterDb);
                }

                Set<String> list = letterDb.get(word.charAt(i));
                if (list == null) {
                    list = new HashSet<>();
                    letterDb.put(word.charAt(i), list);
                }

                list.add(word);
            }
        }

        public Set<String> getList(int i, char c) {
            HashMap<Character, Set<String>> letterDb = indexLetterDb.get(i);
            if (letterDb == null) {
                return null;
            }
            return letterDb.get(c);
        }
    }

    //create the data structure that will store the dictionary
    private HashMap<Integer,FixLengthDB> db = new HashMap<>();
    private List<String> allWords;

    public CWSolution(List<String> allWords)
    {

        //construct the background structure

        this.allWords = allWords;
        //go through each word
        for(String item : allWords) {
            FixLengthDB fixLengthDB = db.get(item.length());

            if (fixLengthDB == null) {
                fixLengthDB = new FixLengthDB();
                db.put(item.length(), fixLengthDB);
            }

            fixLengthDB.storeWord(item);
        }
    }

    public List<String> solutions(String pattern, int maxRequired)
    {

        FixLengthDB fixLengthDB = db.get(pattern.length());
        if (fixLengthDB == null) {
            return new ArrayList<>();
        }

        Set<String> shortList = null;
        int shortListIndex = 0;
        int l = pattern.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            if (pattern.charAt(i) == '*') {
                continue;
            }
            Set<String> set = fixLengthDB.getList(i, pattern.charAt(i));
            if (set == null) {
                return new ArrayList<>();
            }

            if (shortList == null || shortList.size() > set.size()) {
                shortList = set;
                shortListIndex = i;
            }
        }

        if (shortList == null) {
            return allWords;
        }

        HashSet<String> result = new HashSet<>(shortList);
        for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            if (i == shortListIndex || pattern.charAt(i) == '*') {
                continue;
            }
            Set<String> set = fixLengthDB.getList(i, pattern.charAt(i));
            result.retainAll(set);
        }

            // TODO truncate result list according to 'maxRequired' parameter
    return new ArrayList<>(result);
    }
}
```

*Explanation*: The algorithm works in two steps

- Build an index (in the constructor)
- Use index to find matched words (`solutions(...)`)

*Build index*: The index maintain the sets of string for each word-length/character-index/character.

Here how we add words to the index

```
Add word: fun
          |||
          ||\--- (length: 3, position 3, character 'n') -> set{"fun"})
          |\---- (length: 3, position 2, character 'u') -> set{"fun"})
          \----- (length: 3, position 1, character 'f') -> set{"fun"})

Add word: run
          |||
          ||\--- (length: 3, position 3, character 'n') -> set{"fun, run"})
          |\---- (length: 3, position 2, character 'u') -> set{"fun, run"})
          \----- (length: 3, position 1, character 'r') -> set{"run"})

Add word: raw
          |||
          ||\--- (length: 3, position 3, character 'w') -> set{"raw"})
          |\---- (length: 3, position 2, character 'a') -> set{"raw"})
          \----- (length: 3, position 1, character 'r') -> set{"run, raw"})

Add word: rar
          |||
          ||\--- (length: 3, position 3, character 'r') -> set{"rar"})
          |\---- (length: 3, position 2, character 'a') -> set{"raw, rar"})
          \----- (length: 3, position 1, character 'r') -> set{"run, raw, rar"})
```

The database after adding four words (fun, run, raw, rar) is

```
(length: 3, position 1, character 'f') -> set{"fun"})
(length: 3, position 1, character 'r') -> set{"run, raw, rar"})
(length: 3, position 2, character 'u') -> set{"fun, run"})
(length: 3, position 2, character 'a') -> set{"raw, rar"})
(length: 3, position 3, character 'w') -> set{"raw"})
(length: 3, position 3, character 'r') -> set{"rar"})
(length: 3, position 3, character 'n') -> set{"fun, run"})
```

*Use index*: How lets match the pattern `ru*`

First lets find the matching smallest set in the index. We have only 2 non-star characters, so we checking only two sets

```
1: (length: 3, position 1, character 'r') -> set{"run, raw, rar"})
2: (length: 3, position 2, character 'u') -> set{"fun, run"})
```

The smallest set is #2 `{"fun, run"}`. Now we iterate through all other matching sets (in our case the set #1) and calculate intersections:

```
{"fun, run"} cross {"run, raw, rar"} => {"run"}
```

The result is `{"run"}`.

Comment: Could you please explain the algorithm you implemented for the solutions() method. I am having some trouble understanding everything it is doing.

Comment: Added algorithm explanation as requested

Answer (score 2):

If you want to optimize for look-up speed, your ideal solution is where you take **all** that you know (everything about the pattern), and it gives you *only* the set of words that matches. Realistically, you are going to use **some** of what you know to narrow down to a set that is of acceptable size.

In the original code, you are using only one item that you know (i.e. the length) as the key. Millimoose's comments provide the correct answer: create a key that is more discriminating. For instance, suppose you had a two-field key: (Length, Character-Contained)... i.e. 1A, 1B, 1C,... 1Z, 2A... If each pointed to a set, each set would be smaller. You could then use length and any letter from your pattern to get to that set.

Taking it one step further, you could have Millimoose's a three-field key (Length, Position, Character). That way, you take any letter from your pattern, and using those three attributes you can narrow it down to an even smaller list. [As Millimoose points out, what is slowing you down is the String comparisons.]

In theory, you could go all the way and have a set for each possible pattern. For instance, the word "man" would fit patterns `"m**","ma*","m*n","*a*","ma*","*an","**n","m*n" and "*an"`. Each of those could be the key in a map which points to a list (value) that contains the word "man". For instance, "m**" would point to a list that contained "man", "mob", "map", "mid" and so on.

As you do this, you might end up spending too much time initially, when you are constructing the data-structure. Also, you might end up not having enough space to save that data-structure. Those are the trade-offs.

In summary, from your current-key, consider adding more information to the key, while weighing the costs of doing so.

Comment: A set for each possible patterns would be a pretty bad waste of memory. The approach is equivalent to mine - there's no difference between a map from `"m**"` to a list of words, and a map from `(0, 'm')` to the same list. The former would use `2 ^ total_characters_in_dictionary` index entries. The latter only uses `total_characters_in_dictionary` ones.

Comment: Sure, your approach was perfect.